# Angular convert array to object for queryparams

Tags: angular, typescript, https

I have and Angular 12 application in which I have an array of Objects as given below and want to convert this in queryParams so I can route to the generated URL.
So the queryparams should be something like:

Brand:ABC:Brand:XYZ:Size:13x18:Size:51x49x85

```
[{
 "values": ["ABC", "XYZ"],
 "show": true,
 "label": "Brand",
 }, {
 "values": ["13 x 18", "51x49x85"],
 "show": true,
 "label": "Size",
}]
```

I tried using this but its not giving the expected result.

params = new HttpParams({fromObject: { r: myArray }})

Am I missing anything?

Comment: Have you tried manually creating an object first to see what works, and then focussing on how to convert your array to an object with the desired structure?

Comment: 1. Your query string is invalid. It should have `&` before appending new query param and `=` for assigning value to key. 2. [`HttpParamsOptions.fromObject`](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpParamsOptions#fromObject) doesn't support array.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment, your query string is not valid. It should be:

> Brand=ABC&Brand=XYZ&Size=13%20x%2018&Size=51x49x85

And the [`HttpParamsOptions.fromObject`](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpParamsOptions#fromObject) doesn't support for an array.

You need to iterate the array element and form the query string.

1. Iterate each object from the `myArray`.
2. Iterate each element from the `values` array and combine it with the key (`label`). And you should encode the value. Concat each element with `&`.
3. Concat each element with `&`.

```js
let myArray = [{
    "values": ["ABC", "XYZ"],
    "show": true,
    "label": "Brand",
}, {
    "values": ["13 x 18", "51x49x85"],
    "show": true,
    "label": "Size",
}];

let queryString = myArray.map(x => x.values.map(y => `${x.label}=${encodeURI(y)}`).join('&'))
    .join('&');


console.log(queryString);
```

Comment: Thanks @Yong Shun is there a way to remove the space (%20) between 13 and 20. I tried .trim() but does not help.

Comment: Trim works to remove the space at the front and back. You should use the `<string>.replace(/\s/g, "")`, with regex to remove all spaces.